# Manipulation with string which contains HTM:L tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a string

```
const html = "<p><img src="/folder/image.png" /></p><div><img src="www.google.com" /></div>"
```

I need to find all SRC's, define, if they don't contain host names. If no - I need to add host name, like here. And return a new string value.

```
"<p><img src="http://hostname/folder/image.png" /></p><div><img src="www.google.com" /></div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually seeking is this string: `src="/` cause a valid url does not start with `/`  anyway. You can handle this by using String.replace()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

and it's possible to use text or regexp as arg.